# Prism not working inside Vue component

Tags: vue.js, prism, syntax-highlighting

I need source code highlighting. I am using [Prism](http://prismjs.com/).

I tried to paste this code in root of `app` and it was highlighted successfully:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="MainContainer">
    <div class="Header">
      <a href="#">past-code</a>
    </div>
    <component v-bind:is="currentView"></component>
    <code class="language-dart">void main() { } class MyClass {} </code>
    <div class="Footer">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I place the same code in a component, highlighting stops working:

```
Vue.component('view-form', {
  template: `
    <div class="ViewCodeContainer">
    <div class="ViewCode">my code here</div>
    <code class="language-dart">void main() { } class MyClass  </code>
    <div class="ViewCodeMenu">my menu here</div>
    </div>`
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'view-form',
    mycode: ''
  }
})
```

Here is what it looks like in browser:
[image]

It's looking like `Prism` does not work inside a Vue component. Is there any way to force it to work without using npm?

Comment: Hey, check my new edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer:**

There is now a library dedicated to use Prism.js with Vue, check it: https://github.com/egoist/vue-prism-component

```html
<template>
  <prism language="javascript">{{ code }}</prism>
</template>

<script>
import Prism from 'vue-prism-component'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      code: 'const a = b'
    }
  },
  components: {
    Prism
  }
}
</script>
```

**Old answer:**

It does work, see fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x2ax7b2d/

Be sure that you included the languages you are using (here dart), on your selected build, here: http://prismjs.com/download.html

However, Prism is modifying the DOM in a non-vue compliant manner. More precisely, it transforms your `<code>` element into multiple elements over which vue has no control.

So you may face problems in some case. In particular, while you can probably integrate some templating value on the first render, see:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lvn7e3n2/

...you definitely can't refresh the value, at least easily, once it was rendered by Prism, see: 
https://jsfiddle.net/svzvdo1n/

Also, if it does not work for some execution order reason, you can still make Prism re-render, using (probably in your the `mounted` event of your component) Prism.highlightAll or Prism.highlightElement, see the API doc: http://prismjs.com/extending.html#api

I think it could be very interesting to use the raw Prism.highlight(), combined with v-html, for advanced use cases.

**Edit**: I tried, it works really well. Fun. That's most probably the best way to combine Vue and Prism.

```javascript
Vue.component('view-form', {
  template: `
    <div class="ViewCodeContainer">
    <div class="ViewCode">my code here</div>
    <div v-html="highlightedCode">
    </div>
    <textarea v-model="code"></textarea>
    <div class="ViewCodeMenu">my menu here</div>
    </div>`,
    data() {
        return {
        code: 'void main() { } class MyClass'
      }
    },
    computed: {
        highlightedCode() {
        return Prism.highlight(this.code, Prism.languages.dart);
      }
    }
})
```

See complete code:
https://jsfiddle.net/e87Lnvn8/

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-prismjs Seems to work with plugins, e.g.

```
<prism language="javascript" :plugins="['line-highlight']" data-line="1-2" :code="code"></prism>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add a filter like this if you don't want to include an extra library:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Prism from 'prismjs'

// Highlight some code
Vue.filter('highlight', (code, lang = 'javascript') => {
  return Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages[lang], lang)
})
```

and then use that like so in your component template:

```
<pre>
  <code class="language-javascript" v-html="$options.filters.highlight(code)">
  </code>
</pre>
```

Use `class="language-css"` with `$options.filters.highlight(code, 'css')` for css etc, default here is javascript.

The `code` variable is a string defined somewhere, typically in the data section of your component:

```
data () {
  return {
    code: 'const world = "flat"'
  }
}
```

To make the Prism CSS themes work, do `require('../node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism.css')` in `main.js`. Swap the `prism.css` for `prism-tomorrow.css` to change your theme. The list of themes is found in the `node_modules/prismjs/themes` directory.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I needed to call:

```
mounted() {
     Prism.highlightAll();
},
```